# How to use dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

I am trying to use dynamic_cast - with no success.  I have a BASE class, and a class A derived from BASE.  I want to have a pointer to a BASE class object which I later want to cast to class A.  I clearly am not doing this correctly.  The following code compiles:

```
#include <cstdio>

class BASE {
private:

    int i;

public:

     BASE(void) {i = 1; }
     virtual ~BASE(){}

     virtual void id() { printf("CLASS BASE\n"); }
 };

class A : public BASE {
public:
    A(void): BASE() {}
    A(const BASE & base) : BASE(base) {}
    A& operator = (const BASE & base) { static_cast<BASE&>(*this) = base; return *this; }

    void id() override { printf("CLASS A\n"); };
};


int main() {

    BASE* base = new BASE();

    base->id();

    A* a = new A(*base);

    a->id();

    A* anotherA = dynamic_cast<A*>(base);

    if(!anotherA) 
        printf("anotherA is NULL\n");
    else    
        anotherA->id();
}
```

but running it gives:

```
CLASS BASE
CLASS A
anotherA is NULL
```

I am sure I'm missing something very basic, but I keep staring at the code and can't see what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

I have looked at

[When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

but don't understand why dynamic_cast doesn't work - isn't this just a simple downcast?

Comment: `base` is not an instance of `A` so the cast returns nullptr as expected.

Comment: Related: [When should static\_cast, dynamic\_cast, const\_cast and reinterpret\_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: @RetiredNinja If base was an instance of A, why would I need the cast?  I want to effectively treat base as though it was an object of class A.  Is casting base to A not what I need to do?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @JeffR You can't use _`dynamic_cast`_ to change an existing `BASE` instance to an instance of `A`.

Comment: "I want to effectively treat base [which is NOT an A] as though it was an object of class A."  That's not what dynamic_cast will do.  You can use reinterpret_cast.  You'll get undefined behavior, and if you are lucky your application will crash.  If you are unlucky, your application may appear to work.

Comment: Let's say you have another class `B` derived from `BASE`. You have a container of `BASE*` and a mixture of both `A` and `B` instances. `dynamic_cast` can tell you if a particular `BASE*` points to an instance of `A` rather than an instance of `B`. It's usually a code smell if you need to use it for that purpose though as if you can't operate on both `A` and `B` instances through the base then maybe they shouldn't be derived from it.

Comment: "If base was an instance of A, why would I need the cast?" - for example if you had this: `std::vector<BASE*> v; v.push_back(new BASE); v.push_back(new A);` then you could use `dynamic_cast` to determine which of the elements stored in `v` were actually instances of `A` and get to treat them as such.

Comment: Btw; In `BASE(void)` - that `void` to denote an empty argument list is redundant in C++. `BASE()` is fine.

Answer (score 5):

> I am sure I'm missing something very basic

You do.

When you have an *object* of type `A`, and a *pointer* to that object of type `A*`, the *pointer* can be converted to type `BASE*`. This conversion partially *forgets* information about the type.

Now given a pointer of type `BASE*`, *if* this pointer actually points to an `A` object (that is, it was converted from type `A*` at some point), you can *recall* forgotten type information by casting the pointer back to type `A*`.

If your pointer does not point to an object of type `A` to begin with, then nothing was forgotten and there is nothing to recall.